# How to prevent random.sample from generating the same combination of number again?

Tags: python, random

I just wanted to know if there's a way to stop the random.sample from generating the same combination again in list.

So for example combination [4, 6, 1] already appeared in random.sample then I don't want it to appear again to make the matching of my variable code faster.

Thanks

```
import random

code = [2, 6, 4]

while True:
    rand = random.sample(range(0, 10), 3)
    if(rand == code):
        print(str(rand) + " access granted")
        break
    else:
        print(str(rand) + "access denied")
```

Comment: You need to seed the randomiser. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only `10 * 9 * 8 = 720` possible distinct guesses. If you don't want to make the same guess twice, build up a list of all possible guesses (easy to do with nested loops, but even easier to do with itertoools), shuffle that list, and then iterate over it. One implementation:

```
import random, itertools

code = [2, 6, 4]
guesses = [list(p) for p in itertools.permutations(range(10),3)]
random.shuffle(guesses)

for guess in guesses:
    if(guess == code):
        print(guess, "access granted")
        break
    else:
        print(guess, "access denied")
```